# Angular: Why my filter only works if apply the way with the lower performance (?)

Tags: angularjs

Lets do it quickly, my friends

I have a filter which is not working if I do it the recommended way, but if I do it the other way, which is not the proper one, my filter works.

Look, this is the proper way and the same order I have it on my code:

```
<div  class="alert"
      ng-show="!sportF.length">No sports to show
</div> 

<accordion-group is-open="accordionStatus[sport.name]"
                 ng-repeat="sport in sportF = (sports | filter:query)"
                 ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
   <accordion-heading>
            ...
   </accordion-heading>
</accordion-group>
```

and this is not the recommended way, but works as I expected:

```
<div  class="alert"
      ng-show="!(sports | filter:query).length">No sports to show
</div>

<accordion-group is-open="accordionStatus[sport.name]"
                 ng-repeat="sport in sports | filter:query"
                 ng-show="sport.leagues.length">
   <accordion-heading>
            ...
   </accordion-heading>
</accordion-group>
```

is there any mistake with the sort of the code ?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the first way you're showing is the 'proper' way?

Comment: you might wanna put all your code in plunker, so we can figure it out.

Comment: @Vadim because the 2nd way will be iterating twice, got it ? same filter. So the 2nd way is the proper way :)

Comment: introducing into $scope a variable inside view hardly would be called the "proper" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way I see it, it should work.

Here is the example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4x0d4tc/7/)

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <input ng-model="query" type="text"
        placeholder="Filter by" autofocus>
    </form>
    <ul ng-repeat="friend in friendF = ( friends | filter:query ) ">
      <li>{{friend.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>


var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
    { name: "Peter",   age: 20 },
    { name: "Pablo",   age: 55 },
    { name: "Linda",   age: 20 },
    { name: "Marta",   age: 37 },
    { name: "Othello", age: 20 },
    { name: "Markus",  age: 32 }
  ];

  $scope.filterFunction = function(element) {
    return element.name.match(/^Ma/) ? true : false;
  };

});
```

Comment: what I do not have working is the alert to show when nothing match the search

Comment: you mean ```ng-show="!sportF">No sports to show``` ? still not working

Comment: any other solution ? or a way to convert that data into an array ?

Comment: very interesting. http://jsfiddle.net/e4x0d4tc/6/ it does show but you need to type more than 1 character. Btw, I was wrong it is an array from the beginning.

Comment: I am getting crazy here. But I guess I should do it with the 'wrong' way.

Comment: ah ha ! after I linked my example to correct angularjs version (1.2.28), it works ! http://jsfiddle.net/e4x0d4tc/7/ . case close ! go home :)